# Laravel error on Cloudways only: No hint path defined for [theme]

Tags: laravel

I have a site built on Laravel, and on my local server + MySQL it runs well, and when I deployed to Digital Oceans app platform, it works well there. But for some reason when I deploy to Cloudways, I get this error.

> No hint path defined for [theme]

I'm using a pre-built thing called [Wave](https://devdojo.com/wave) that uses Laravel, and a few other things like Voyager to have a functioning member-ready site. It works really well, but something about it does not seem to jive with Cloudways, and my only thought is that it could be something about the database configuration or something,  but I have no clue. I tried a brand new Wave install just to test, and it still happens on all fresh everything.

I can't imagine this would help much but here's a video of the process to set up wave on Cloudways specifically that I used to install it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5505CUNH9x4

I'm a bit new to this so apologies if I left out any other crucial info. Any ideas what this could be?

[image: Error screen]

Comment: try php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: @JohnLobo I just tried, but no luck :/. Do I need to do anything to reload something server related for this to take effect? Or would it just work if it was the correct solution?

Comment: not sure exactly .i would run optimize command usually and php artisan clear .not sure what exactly causing in your case

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.